# Hellenistic Period or Hellenistic period?

Tags: capitalization

Is the correct capitalization Hellenistic **Period** or Hellenistic **period**?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the word ***Hellenistic*** in Longman Dictionary shows that ***"Hellenistic"*** is followed by ***period*** with lower case ***p***.

So I think *"period"* with lower case is better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically. However, if (as I believe is true) there is a specific period of history that is known by many people using the term 'Hellenistic Period', then I would say that is a proper name, and so it should be capitalised.

If that is not the case, then Hellenistic is still capitalised but period is not; it's just a period of time.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hellenistic+Period%2C+Hellenistic+period&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHellenistic%20Period%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHellenistic%20period%3B%2Cc0) shows that lower case is 6 times more common.